# Datagrid Set focus on newly added row

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid bound to an observable collection.
When the user press the "add button" it adds a new row and I do this by adding a new element to the observablecollection.

I cannot figure out how to make the newly added row with the first cell in focus as if we were editing. I am using a MVVM pattern.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

[The answer given by Gauss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33004666/200443) is the right approach, but with some code, it is clearer:

```
void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Loaded += Row_Loaded;
}

void Row_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    var row = (DataGridRow) sender;
    row.Loaded -= Row_Loaded;
    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dataGrid, row, 0);
    if (cell != null) cell.Focus();
    dataGrid.BeginEdit();        
}

static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow row, int column)
{
    if (dataGrid == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dataGrid");
    if (row == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("row");
    if (column < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("column");

    DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
    if (presenter == null)
    {
        row.ApplyTemplate();
        presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
    }
    if (presenter != null)
    {
        var cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
        if (cell == null)
        {
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(row, dataGrid.Columns[column]);
            cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
        }
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}

static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        var visualChild = child as T;
        if (visualChild != null)
            return visualChild;
        var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
        if (childOfChild != null)
            return childOfChild;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You retrieve the row in the `DataGrid.LoadingRow` event, but the cell is not yet available. So you put an handler on the `Loaded` event in order to wait for this event to occur and then you can retrieve the cell and put the focus on it.

The handler is removed to avoid a new triggering.

The editing session can also be started with `dataGrid.BeginEdit()`.

All of this is in the code-behind, because it belongs to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing the DataGrid's `LoadingRow` (or similar) event.  Do a `SetFocus(e.Row)` (or similar) on the row.  This is purely View-oriented, so it conforms to MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
DataGridCell cell = GetCell(rowIndex, colIndex);
cell.Focus;
```

Of course you need that elusive GetCell() method. Vincent Sibal from MSFT wrote up that method (and the required GetRow as well) in [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/63974f4f-d9ee-45af-8499-42f29cbc22ae).  I was searching for something else when I came across this so I haven't used it but others seem to have had good luck with it. You'll notice there are links to [his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/) which you might also find helpful for all things DataGrid related.

Answer (score 0):

Hopes that will help others.
i'll show the MVVM way, in the View:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="3" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date"  Binding="{Binding mydate}" MinWidth="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding Count}" MinWidth="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" SourceName="dg1" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DgSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg1}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>

    </i:Interaction.Triggers>          
</DataGrid>
```

now in the View-Model: 
you need to set the SelectedIndex after : add, remove, etc...and

```
 private ICommand dgSelectionChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// when the datagrid Selection Changes
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand DgSelectionChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return dgSelectionChanged ??
            (dgSelectionChanged = new RelayCommand<DataGrid>(dg1 =>
            {
              // whatever you want when the Selection Changes


                SelectedIndex= d
                //select the item 
                if (dg1.SelectedIndex > -1)
                {
                    dg1.Focus();
                    dg1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg1.Items[dg1.SelectedIndex], dg1.Columns[0]);
                }
            }));
        }
    }
```

by the way, to select the first row after control loaded, add this to the view:

```
        <!-- select the row after control loaded -->
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" SourceName="dg1" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DgSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg1}"/>  
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

thanks, Avi.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was a combination of `LoadingRow`, `e.Row.Loaded` and the `GetCell()` method of the following link:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx

The `DataGrid.LoadingRow` event is called before the cell is available through `GetCell`. But in the `DaraGridRow.Loaded` event, the cell is available.

After that, you can use `cell.Focus()` and `DataGrid.BeginEdit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in my case thanks to Jake Berger's answer.

Binding the DataGrid's SelectedItem and handling the LoadingRow event works beautifully.

e.g.:

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataItem, Mode=TwoWay}" LoadingRow="MyDataGrid_LoadingRow"></DataGrid>
```

```
private void MyDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
          SelectedDataItem = (MyDataObject)e.Row.Item;
}
```